# Which OWLs did Fred and George Weasley achieve?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Goblet of Fire* it's stated that the Weasley twins achieved three Ordinary Wizarding Levels each. Considering their generally laidback approach to their education, it seems like these would be three subjects that they naturally excel at (at least comparatively to the others they took) and therefore would be able to pass exams in without much study.

Throughout the books they've shown a lot of potential to have achieved much better results (a fact commented on by Ron in *Order of the Phoenix* when they're developing the Skiving Snackboxes), demonstrating a particular affinity for (I'd guess) Potions, Transfiguration and Charms.

Is there any information about which subjects they achieved OWLs in and which grades they received?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, we actually have enough information in the books to deduce all but one of their OWL subjects.

**Charms** – in *Order of the Phoenix*, both Fred and George mention having a lesson inspected by Umbridge. Since *Order of the Phoenix* would be their seventh year at Hogwarts (so NEWT year), this means they must both have taken (and passed) Charms OWL.

It’s clear that Flitwick was impressed with both of their work — when their Portable Swamp appears in the castle, he leaves a portion of it intact as a testament to their ability (and propensity for mischief).

**Defence Against the Dark Arts** — in *Order of the Phoenix*, the pair get told off for playing Exploding Snap in Umbridge’s class. Again, this is NEWT year, so they must both have passed DADA OWL.

**Transfiguration** – in *Goblet of Fire* (iirc), Professor McGonagall tells George to continue transfiguring his raccoon. Since this is the year after he would have finished OWLs, we can assume that he passed Transfiguration OWL also.

His ability for transfiguration is shown from an early age — consider, for example, how he turned Ron’s teddy bear into a spider at age five.

This gives us three for George, but the final OWL for Fred is unaccounted for. His OWLs are never named in the books, but some people believe his third OWL was **Herbology**. In *Order of the Phoenix*, the twins are going to sell Extendable Ears before Herbology. This suggests that at least one of them is attending Herbology classes, and since it isn’t George, as he is already in three other NEWT classes, Fred seems like the natural fit.

I don’t have any information about which subjects they took and failed. You could probably read the first three books to find out which subjects they mention for OWL, but I don’t think we’d learn much from that.

So two of your three guesses were right. As for Potions, we know that Snape wouldn’t have accepted them for NEWT unless they got Outstanding (which is probably pretty unlikely), so I think they probably didn’t bother studying. Indeed, I’d guess that the pair picked these subjects purposefully, because it would have given them plenty of time in sixth and seventh years for… “other” endeavours.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from alexwichan's answer, I'd also like to point to the possibility that one of the twins also took Potions and Care of Magical Creatures and passed upto OWL levels, as they have Love Potions(quite complex) and Pygmy Puffs(they breed them in the shop) in the Weasley's Wizard Wheezes shop. Their best subjects were Charms, Transfiguration and DADA, but it's a possibility they took and passed these subjects.

Comment: It’s not really a possibility that they passed these subjects at OWL level, since we know that they each got exactly three OWLs, no more.

Comment: What if Fred -> Transfiguration, Charms, DADA; George -> Herbology, Potions, Care of Magical Creatures? It's possible. It's never really indicated that both the twins were present in the same class. Only indication of them being ever together at school was during breaks and in the common room and Owlery in HP4.

Comment: It is, actually—see Alex’ answer. They definitely both took DADA and Charms.